# Show $\mathbb P(A\triangle B)=0$

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(\Omega,\cal F,\mathbb P)$ a $\sigma$-finite measure space, $T:\Omega\to\Omega$ measure preserving and $A\in\cal F$ with $\mathbb P(A\triangle T^{-1}(A))=0$ and $B:=\{x\in\Omega\mid x\in T^{-n}(A) \text{ infinitely often}\}.$

> Show $\mathbb P(A\triangle B)=0$.

It has been shown that $B$ is $T$-invariant. Is it possible to write $B$ in terms of intersections and unions or how should one handle this here? Help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write $B$ in terms of intersectons and unions. Hint: consider sets
$$
U_i = \bigcup_{j > i} T^{-j}(A).
$$
Can you express $B$ in terms of $U_i$?

Comment: $B= \cap_{n=0}^\infty \cup_{j=n}^\infty T^{-j}(A)$ or?

Comment: Yes, this is what I was hinting at.